# Get the path of the parent shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, parent, pid

I am writing a Python program that needs to know the executable location of the shell that the script was executed from. For example, I would expect to find `/usr/bin/env/{bash,zsh,fish}` or otherwise. How would I do this?

Unfortunately, I can't give a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, because I don't know where to start. I haven't been able to find anything online.

I've looked into `psutil`, at least. I've tried to get the PID of the parent process but I've just gotten the PID of the current Python process instead.

Comment: `import os; os.getcwd()`?

Comment: @Vlad Not even close. Why would I want the current working directory?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: The `SHELL` environment variable points to the current shell path. Can that be used?

Comment: @Shiva No, `SHELL` refers to your *default* shell, which may or may not be shell that started the script.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem; why do you need or care about what shell started your script?

Comment: @chepner Why are you challenging my intended purpose? My program has a use for such details, that's all you should care about. It's a system utility that needs to know these things to help the user configure their environment.

Comment: @spikespaz If you know what you are doing, congratulations. Many people who post a question like this don't, which is why we ask when someone tries to do something out of the ordinary, and why the term ["XY problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) exists in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `psutil` should be more or less straightforward:

```
import psutil
print(psutil.Process().parent().exe())
```

Let me explain the code:

- `Process()`, without arguments this creates a `Process` object for the running process, that is the Python interpreter.
- `.parent()` gets the parent `Process()`, that is probably the shell.
- `.exe()` gets the path of the executable of the parent process.

Depending on your setup, you may need some additional path, but that should be enough for the simplest cases.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer not because the others don't work, but because of the step-by-step explanation. While not necessary for me to understand it, the explanation may help anyone in the future who crosses this question. It is also cross-patform, while the solutions using the `ps` command are not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `subprocess` module to get the output the `ps` command:

```
import subprocess, re

psoutput = subprocess.check_output(['ps','-o','pid,cmd'])
```

which in my case outputs:

```
  PID CMD
 9650 bash
10290 python app.py
10291 ps -o pid,cmd
```

Then you could parse that output to extract the shell PID:

```
pid = re.findall('\s*(\d+)\s*(bash|zsh|fish)',psoutput)[0][0]
```

which outputs `9650` in my case.

From the PID, you can extract the path like this (in my case PID = 9650):

```
path = subprocess.check_output(['readlink','-f','/proc/'+pid+'/exe'])
```

which outputs in my case:

```
/bin/bash
```